# Notepad++ Find Replace Cisco alias phones

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some phone load aliases that need modification. Need syntax to find/replace in notepad++. I'm sure there needs to be a wildcard for the subdirectory number (7940,etc) but I cant figure it out. I have about 50 lines with different number subdirectories. I think I have the find, I just need the replace...I need the replace to reflect the changing number subdirectory for each line. I used a wildcard for the find, so it finds each line regardless of number subdirectory, but I don't know how to replace using the number subdirectory that is present in the line.

currently:

```
tftp-server flash:/PHONES/7940/P003-8-12-00.bin

tftp-server flash:/PHONES/8831/kern8831.9-3-3-5.sebn
```

each line needs to be modified to:

```
tftp-server flash:/PHONES/7940/P003-8-12-00.bin alias P003-8-12-00.bin

tftp-server flash:/PHONES/8831/kern8831.9-3-3-5.sebn alias kern8831.9-3-3-5.sebn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing group (`(...)`) and backreference (`\1`).

Find (trailing filename which does not contains `/`):

```
([^/]+)$
```

Replace with:

```
\1 alias \1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with capturing groups and replacement along with *Greedy* way.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gA3pT6/4)

In Notepad++

Find what: `.*\/(.*)`

Replace with: `$0 alias $1`

Here `$0` will match whole line whereas `$1` will match anything that is after last slash.

**Note:** keep `.` matches newline check box off.

---

Pattern explanation:

```
  .*               any character except \n (0 or more times (most possible))
  \/               '/'
  (                group and capture to \1:
    .*               any character except \n (0 or more times (most possible))
  )                end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
tftp-server flash:/PHONES/(\d+)/([-.\w]+)
```

Replace:

```
tftp-server flash:/PHONES/\1/\2 alias \2
```